# Problem when including code in a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I don't know if it is the right place to post this, but it seemed to me I would be more likely to get an answer there.

Currrently working on SAS for an internship, I am trying to write a macro in order to automate the process of finding a fitting `ARIMA` model for my data sets. I am very new to this software, and quite not a specialist in the field of statistics.

However, while I seemingly understood how to import my files and launch the `proc arima`, I am stuck on a little problem. A part of my code, which is working fine if I write it outside of the macro (I guess it's called `open code` ?) like this :

```
data _null_;
set Lib.out;    /* Lib.out contains the data of the OUTSTAT statement of the PROC ARIMA */
x = 1000000;
put _STAT_;     /* Prints correctly the names of the different lines in the log */
if _STAT_='AIC' then do;  /* _STAT_ is a column and AIC the name of a line AFAIK */
    if _VALUE_ < x then
        x = _VALUE_;
    put x;
    put _STAT_;  /* Here only prints AIC, which I guess is correct inside of the IF loop */
end;
run;
```

But when running it inside a macro such as :

```
%macro recherche(poste=, mto=);
    --- code ---

data _null_;
set Lib.out;    /* Lib.out contains the data of the OUTSTAT statement of the PROC ARIMA */
%let aic0 = 1000000;
%put _STAT_;     /* Doesn't recognize the _STAT_ statement and stops */
%if _STAT_='AIC' %then %do;
    %if _VALUE_ < &aic0 %then %do;
        &aic0 = _VALUE_;
        data Lib.chosen;
        set Lib.model;   /* Contains the OUTMODEL statement of PROC ARIMA */
        run;
    %end;
end;
run;

    --- code ---
```

I tried to search for similar cases on the internet but couldn't find an explanation for what I am looking for. Plus, being new to SAS, the official documentation is still hard to understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you're doing there doesn't need the `%`.  You just need that if it's a statement controlling which lines of code are even sent to the compiler.

```
%macro recherche(mto=);
data _null_;
set Lib.out;    /* Lib.out contains the data of the OUTSTAT statement of the PROC ARIMA */
x = &mto.;
put _STAT_;     /* Prints correctly the names of the different lines in the log */
if _STAT_='AIC' then do;  /* _STAT_ is a column and AIC the name of a line AFAIK */
    if _VALUE_ < x then
        x = _VALUE_;
    put x;
    put _STAT_;  /* Here only prints AIC, which I guess is correct inside of the IF loop */
end;
run;
%mend recherche;
```

That's assuming the MTO parameter is intended to hold the value assigned to x.  The only time you would use %IF is if you did something like

```
%macro recherche(mto=,stat=);
data _null_;
set Lib.out;    /* Lib.out contains the data of the OUTSTAT statement of the PROC ARIMA */
x = &mto.;
put _STAT_;     /* Prints correctly the names of the different lines in the log */
%if &stat=AIC %then %do;
  if _STAT_='AIC' then do;  /* _STAT_ is a column and AIC the name of a line AFAIK */
    if _VALUE_ < x then
        x = _VALUE_;
    put x;
    put _STAT_;  /* Here only prints AIC, which I guess is correct inside of the IF loop */
  end;
%end;
%else %if &stat=XYZ %then %do;
  *more code ...;

%end;
run;
%mend recherche;
```

That would only do one or the other of those sections of code.  Macro statements don't have access to the data in the proc or data step, and they don't use quotes (unless the quote is an actual important part of the code).

Comment: Oh I thought every piece of code that was writen into a macro had to be somehow "protected" by the `%` symbol. I tried your version with some modifications (`poste` is the name of a power substation and `mto` stands for the meteo station closest to the substation), but now it seems the compiler doesn't recognize the `end;` statement. I get this error : `There were 2 unclosed DO blocks.` even though I only have 2 DO blocks in my code and they're both closed like in your example. I'll try to have a look and see what I can come up with.

Comment: In the end, I made another version where I don't need the the comparison (and thus don't need the DO blocks). Anyway thanks for the explanation that was actually pretty useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when combining a pipe statement do while loop within a macro. I would get the unclosed do loop error, yet the statements would work independently. I had tried every iteration to resolve, but to no avail. Finally, the solution for me was to put the pipe infile statement into its own program and then bring it into the macro using a %include. This worked perfectly! The issue is definitely a bug within SAS.